# How to make a bulk save reactive with RxJava and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming

What I am trying to accomplish is to create something in bulk reactively with a POST request. Lets say I want to create a User in bulk, so FE will send me 5 User's that I need to persist, and as a response I want the 5 Users's with id's.

I have gotten to a point where I can create each User in a separate thread, but I can't figure out how to return a response with each User in a list, I can't really get into posting the code because its work related, so rather I would like someone to point me in the direction or provide a simple example if possible!

Basically I can create this logic using an executor but trying to do it reactively with RxJava.

My pseudo code looks something like

FE sends list of User objects, 
for each User in Users, 
create User(returns observable), 
in a loop subscribe to each User

is subscribing to each User the wrong approach? I guess I am still trying to figure out how to make this process 'reactive'

here is a snippet of  the  code creating in bulk

```
 List<User> f = new ArrayList<>();
        lineItems.stream().forEach(u -> {
            logger.info(">>>>>>>> CREATING user OBSERVABLES: THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Observable<User> usrObs =
                    createUsr(headerId, user, pa);
            usrObs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(t -> {
                f.add(t);
            });
        });
        return Observable.just(f);
```

In this case the list is always empty, how do I make it populate? I am returning a deferred result in the controller and usually when I subscribe it always works, but I have never doing something in bulk.

edit: I think I got this working correctly by using zip and seeing returned values, and only passing in 1 parameter. I can see each request run on a different thread, but it still seems a little slow. Still searching for correct examples

Comment: I would think that the reactive approach would just be to push the items in a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a new subscription for each lineItem and that subscription is not reaching onNext necessarily before you return from the method because you are doing the work on another thread.  In other words, they just haven't had a chance to be added, but the returned Observable is ready to emit the list reference right away.  I would use Rx the whole way through to ensure the returned Observable emits exactly what you expect.

Something like

```
return Observable
 .from(lineItems) //emit each line item
 .observeOn(Schedulers.io())  // move off the thread
 .map(lineItem -> createUsr(headerId, lineItem, pa) //take action
 .toList() //put all the emitted items back into one list
```

The important note is this work will not happen until you subscribe to the Observable that is returned.